# Softlayer VSI total Sotrage

Tags: rest, api, storage, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

This REST call displays a list of VMs with CPU, Mem, Storage...how can I sum up total storage instead of displaying individual disk size?

```
https://APIID:Key@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,hostname,primaryIpAddress,primaryBackendIpAddress,maxCpu,maxMemory,domain,fullyQualifiedDomainName,createDate,operatingSystem[id,softwareDescription[longDescription]],networkVlans[vlanNumber,primarySubnetId,name],datacenter[name],powerState[keyName],blockDevices[id,mountType,diskImage[capacity]]]
```

Thanks
Behzad

Answer (score 1):

This bit of python should work for you.

```
"""
Goes through each virtual guest, prints out the FQDN, each disk and its size
and then the total size for disks on that virtual guest.
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

class example():

    def __init__(self):

        self.client = SoftLayer.Client()

    def main(self):
        mask = "mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,blockDevices[diskImage[type]]]"
        guests = self.client['SoftLayer_Account'].getVirtualGuests(mask=mask)
        for guest in guests:
            self.getSumStorage(guest)

    def getSumStorage(self, guest):
        """
            Gets the total disk space for each virtual guest.
            DOES NOT COUNT SWAP SPACE in this total
        """
        print("%s" % guest['fullyQualifiedDomainName'])
        sumTotal = 0
        for device in guest['blockDevices']:
            try:
                if device['diskImage']['type']['keyName'] == 'SWAP':
                    print("\tSWAP: %s  - %s GB  (not counted)" %(device['device'],device['diskImage']['capacity']) )
                    continue
                else:
                    print("\tDisk: %s  - %s GB" %(device['device'],device['diskImage']['capacity']) )
                    sumTotal = sumTotal + device['diskImage']['capacity']
            except KeyError:
                continue
        print("TOTAL: %s GB" % sumTotal)
        return sumTotal

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = example()
    main.main()
```

Will output something like this:

```
$ python diskSum.py
LAMP1.asdf.com
    Disk: 0  - 25 GB
    SWAP: 1  - 2 GB  (not counted)
TOTAL: 25 GB
LAMP2.asdf.com
    Disk: 0  - 25 GB
    SWAP: 1  - 2 GB  (not counted)
TOTAL: 25 GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Take account REST requests are only used to retrieve data of each [datatype object](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes), it means you wont be able to perform any calculation through REST.

In order to get the total storage, I recommend you to use some language like [Python](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python), [Java](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java), [C#](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/C-Sharp), [Ruby](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-ruby), [Golang](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go), etc. which are supported by SoftLayer. See [Softlayer API Overview](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/softlayer-api-overview)